# Why am I getting only first character in array stored in Session?

Tags: php

I have an array (mysql query result) stored in $_SESSION variable.

Now, I try to access a member of that array like:

```
$_SESSION["template"]["key"]
```

Now, the problem is that it gives only first character of the string "key". Strangely, it runs perfectly on localhost and also did on my previous hosting. (I am now on hostgator).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it means that your `$_SESSION["template"]` variable is a *string*, thus, `$_SESSION["template"]["key"]` 
 evaluated to `$_SESSION["template"][0]` and returns first character.

Why your $_SESSION["template"] is a string instead of being an array - is a matter of debugging. You may start it right now.

If you have `register_globals` on and some variable called `$tamplate`, it may rewrite $_SESSION contents

Comment: Okay, got it. I then must store all variables separatly. Isn't there a way to store arrays and other data types in SESSION?

Comment: @ShashankJain: It is. Just change "template" to an array

Comment: @ShashankJain Yes. You can store arrays and objects in the session.

Comment: i stored result of mysql_fetch_array into $_SESSION["template"]. like `$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);` and `$_SESSION["template"] = $info;` is this wrong?

Comment: @ShashankJain the code is ok, there is some other code making it wrong. see update for one possible reason

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - thanks a million! man it would have taken me lifetime to figure that out!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$_SESSION["template"]` isn't an array but a string. `["key"]` is considered as index `[0]` which results in the first character

So your code is the same as `$_SESSION["template"][0]`

Comment: Oh!! So, is there a way out of this? Except that I must store variables separately.

Comment: @ShashankJain: You must have "template" as an array in order to be able to do such things. Your "template" is currently a string

Comment: but i stored result of mysql_fetch_array into $_SESSION["template"].

Comment: @ShashankJain: You didn't probably.

Comment: @ShashankJain: You did the mistake here `$_SESSION["template"] = $info;`. Don't do it